# How to properly split common dependencies with webpack4

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-4

I am having difficulty configuring webpack4 to properly bundle shared dependencies.

I have two pages in my application (Page1 and Page2). Both require `bootstrap`, `jquery` as well as a custom JavaScript app called `core`.

Page 2 requires the same but also a custom JavaScript application called `my-app` and also `lodash`.

Since my `core` app will be included in all pages, I want to have `jquery` and `bootstrap` in the same bundle.

Since `lodash` is only required for pages running `my-app`, I want to include that dependency in the `my-app` bundle.

So I setup my app like this:

**webpack.config.js**

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');


module.exports = {
  entry: {
    'core': './src/core/index.js',
    'my-app': './src/my-app/index.js'
  },
  output: {
    filename: '[name].bundle.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
  },
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      jquery: 'jquery/src/jquery',
    }
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      $: "jquery",
      jQuery: "jquery"
    }),
  ],
  mode: 'development',
}
```

**page1.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Page1</title>

    <script src="dist/core.bundle.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Page1</h1>
    <span id="test"></span>
  </body>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#test').text('jQuery Works!');
    });
  </script>
</html>
```

**page2.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Page1</title>

    <script src="dist/core.bundle.js"></script>
    <script src="dist/my-app.bundle.js"></script>

  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Page2</h1>
    <span id="test"></span>
  </body>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#test').text('jQuery Works!');
    });
  </script>
</html>
```

(Full project: https://github.com/LondonAppDev/webpack-split-example)

When I run `npx webpack`, it creates `core.bundle.js` and `my-app.bundle.js`, however *both* of these include `jquery`.

Is it possible to put all "global" dependencies in `core.bundle.js`?

Comment: Look at common chunks with vendor/manifest optimizing

Comment: https://github.com/webpack/webpack/tree/master/examples/common-chunk-and-vendor-chunk

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just one thing to remember here, with webpack 4 you don't add vendor scripts as an entry to your webpack.config, just real entry scripts to your application.
WP will create an optimized bundle output for your app using the default settings.

You have to add vendor cache group to your config, in order to extract `jQuery, Lodash, Bootstrap,Popper` into a separate bundle:

```
 optimization: {
    splitChunks: {
      cacheGroups: {       
        vendor: {
          test: /node_modules/,
          name: "vendor",
          chunks: "all", 
          enforce: true
        }
      }
    }
  },
```